# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Couldn't find User without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I made a simple voting system for users

votes_controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @vote = Vote.create(author_uid: current_user.uid)
  @user.votes << @vote

  redirect_to root_url
end
```

view file:

```
- @users.each do |user|
  %tr
    %td= user.id
    %td= link_to user.username, user.url
    %td
      = link_to 'Like', {:controller => "votes", :action => "create" }, :method => "post"
```

But if I vote for user there is an error "Couldn't find User without an ID"

Hope you will help to solve this problem. If you need more information, please comment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing in an `id` param in your `link_to` method.

That is why the `params[:id]` doesnt exist when you try to look it up on the server

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
link_to 'Like', {:controller => "votes", :action => "create" }, :method => "post"
```

to

```
link_to 'Like', {:controller => "votes", :action => "create", :id => user.id }, :method => "post"
```

Also, you're not saving your user object after creating the votes object.